# Getting current time of a timezone

Tags: java

I am trying to get current time of a particular timeZone but when I write this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Boise"));
System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

it always prints UTC time followed by "UTC" word maybe because on the server timeZone is set to UTC but still it shouldn't happen as I explicitly specified the timezone here.

Comment: A Calendar instance is stored in UTC.  You have to use a SimpleDateFormat and specify the time zone to get the date and time for a particular timezone.

Comment: yes ""America/Boise"" is supported TimeZone ID. you can check this by calling java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs().

Comment: With Java 8: `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Boise"))`...

Answer (score 0):

It returns UTC because the method `TimeZone.getTimeZone(String id)` returns the specified TimeZone, or the GMT zone if the given ID cannot be understood. In your case, since the given ID cannot b understood, it returns the GMT Zone.

Comment: "America/Boise" is a supported  Timezone ID as can be verified by java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs().